# Valid SSL certificate issuing fradulent certificates

Tags: security, ssl, https

I believe I mostly understand the verification chain related to SSL certificates. However there is a scenario I am unsure about.
Consider this scenario:
a trusted CA signs a certificate for Server A. 
The owner of this valid certificate uses the Server A private/public key to sign a fraudulent certificate for a malicious entity (Server B).

If a client were to connect to another entity and malicious server B was in the middle, couldn't it send back its certificate and be verified by the client as being authentic?
i.e. Server B sends its public cert and Server A's cert, the client machine verifies that:
trusted CA issued server As cert (so its valid) and server As key was used to issue server B (since A is trusted, B is trusted).

I guess phrased in another way, does every intermediate certificate authority need to be in the trusted certificate store (it seems like the answer is yes)

Answer (score 1):

A normal SSL certificate can't be using for signing other certificates. You need a signing certificate. A trusted CA will only sign a signing certificate for an entity that it also trusts, and there is a whole 'nother level of checking around that.

Comment: That makes sense, if a trusted CA issues me a CA, does this CA that gets issued to me need to be in the trusted CAs of the client?

Comment: @UserWPFWindows: first, no public trusted CA will issue you a CA certificate unless you can really prove that you know what you are doing, that you can keep the necessary infrastructure very safe and that you pay lots and lots of money. And, this intermediate CA does not need to be in the clients CA store since it is signed by a trusted CA - it has to be sent by the server as chain certificate though .